# CoordinatesToCellName undefined (type *excelize.File has no field or method CoordinatesToCellName)

Tags: golang

Использую библиотеку https://github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize v1.4.1 , хочу получить ячейку по координатам (x, y).

Для этого в документации используется функция CoordinatesToCellName, но она доступна начиная с версии 2.0.0

Как обновить библиотеку до новейшей версии?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала убедитесь, что ваш проект работает в режиме
модулей. Далее, просто замените импорт:

```golang
import "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
```

На:

```golang
import "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize/v2"
```

Возможно, понадобится ещё `go mod tidy`.

Comment: Хотел сам ответить на свой вопрос, да забыл, ну будет твой ответ)